# Remove or hide 'cancel' suggested input in google assistant

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dialogflow-es

I am developing a chatbot application using Dialogflow and Firebase cloud functions. For testing I am using Google Assistant. When I run the application in Google Assistant it shows suggested input with 'cancel' text by default. I have created one intent for `cancel` and added an event for it. When executing the application, if I provide `cancel` as input then it directly triggers the event provided in the cancel intent and exits the application. In my application, if I want to cancel payment or cancel transfer funds then I use the cancel word as training phrase and it just cancels payment instead of closing the application.
For reference please find attached simulator image link with question.

I have checked from where these 'cancel' suggestions actually come. It is predefined suggestion text which comes in an application. So I am unable to find out from where it is actually come.

```
app.intent('askCancel', (conv) => {

  conv.user.storage = {};

  isBalanceCheck = isTransactionCheck = false;

  deleteContext(conv);

  conv.contexts.delete('ask-service-context');

  conv.close("Thank you for using this application. Have a nice day.");
});
```

This intent for cancel ends the conversation. So while cancelling the payment the above intent should not be called.

It should perform cancel payment and continues the execution.[Google Assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV9Ez.png)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for conversation exits is available [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/conversation-exits).

In summary, when a user tells the Google Assistant, "exit", "cancel", "stop", "nevermind", or "goodbye", the Google Assistant will end the conversation immediately.

As an `Actions on Google` developer, your only option is to send a single [simple response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#simple_responses) with a 60-character limit on its textToSpeech and displayText values.

What you're trying to do -- process the cancel intent yourself, then continue the conversation -- isn't currently possible.

Comment: I have one task in my application where i can transfer funds or payment. In this task need to ask confirmation. So after confirmation need to provide an input by saying yes for continue payment or by saying cancel or end for stoping the payment process. If i say cancel or anything which ends the payment then it directly ends my conversation. But while payment or funds transfer if i say cancel then my conversation should be continued.